# How to execute next stage in sequential stages inspite of previous stage failure in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

At the moment I have two stages defined in Jenkins because they both need different agents.

Here is my Proof of concept code

```
stages {
    stage("Run Tests"){
        agent docker
        stage("Do setup"){}
        stage("Testing") {}
        post{
            always{
                echo "always"
            }
            failure {
                echo "failure"
            }
        }
    }
    stage("Generate Reports"){
        agent node-label
        stage("Generate"){

        }
    }
}
```

I need "Generate reports" on different agent since certain binaries are on the node and not inside docker container. Tests run inside docker share volume on node so I get all artifacts that are needed to generate report on the node

*(I have tried to run "Generate reports" in post stage, but it seems to run inside docker container somehow.)*

Now if "Run Tests" fails, "Generate reports" is skipped due to previous stage failure. Any idea how I can force "Generate reports" stage to be run even on failure of previous stage.

Comment: do you need any more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the pipeline.

```
pipeline {
agent none
stages {
    stage("Run Tests"){
    agent { label "agent1" }
        stages  {           
            stage("Do setup"){
                steps{
                    sh 'exit 0'
                    }
                }
            stage("Testing") {
                steps {
                    catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    sh "exit 1"
                        } //catchError
                    } //steps
                post{
                    always{
                        echo "always"
                        }
                    failure {
                        echo "failure"
                        }
                    } // post
                } // Testing
            } // stages
        } // Run Test

    stage("Generate Reports"){
        agent { label "agent2" }
            steps {
                sh 'exit 0'
            }
        } // Reports
    }    
}
```

The pipeline is successful, but stage **Testing** is showed as failed, you can choose the status of **buildResult** and **stageResult** in case you want it to be unstable or fail:

[image]

Comment: So I ended up using Option 3 which seemed logical for my needs Here is my implementation `catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'SUCCESS', message: 'Tests Failed'){}`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run "Generate Reports" stage always then you could mark your earlier stages as `unstable` if there are failures. 
By this way Jenkins will execute all stages and will not stop on errors at a particular stage.
Example:

```
stages {
    stage("Run Tests"){
        agent docker
        stage("Do setup"){}
        stage("Testing") {
          steps {
                script {
            // To show an example, Execute "set 1" which will return failure 
            def result = bat label: 'Check bat......', returnStatus: true, script: "set 1"
                   if (result !=0) {
                   // If the result status is not 0 then mark this stage as unstable to continue ahead 
                   // and all later stages will be executed 
                   unstable ('Testing failed')
                   }
                }
            }
         }
    }
}
    stage("Generate Reports"){
        agent node-label
        stage("Generate"){

        }
    }
}
```

Option 2 , if you dont want to handle via return status , you can use `try and catch block`

```
stage("Testing") {
          steps {
                script {
                 try {
                        // To show an example, Execute "set 1" which will return failure 
                         bat "set 1"
                   }
                   catch (e){
                   unstable('Testing failed!')
                   }
                }
            }
         }
```

Option 3: You can change the return status as success of complete build irrespective of stage failure.

```
stage("Testing") {
          steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE'){
                script {
                         // To show an example, Execute "set 1" which will return failure 
                         bat "set 1"
                   }
                }
            }
```

**NOTE**: **Option 3** has a drawback it will not execute further steps in the same stage if at all there were any errors. 
Example: 
In this example, the print message "Testing stage" will not be executed as there were issues in `bat set 1` command

```
stage("Testing") {
          steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE'){
                script {
                         // To show an example, Execute "set 1" which will return failure 
                         bat "set 1"
                         // Note : Below step will not be executed since there was failure in prev step
                         println "Testing stage"
                   }
                }
            }
```

Option 4 : which you already tried out to keep Generate Reports stage in the Post always
 section of the build so that is executed always irrespective of any failure.