# Continue sequential stages even if parallel stages fail

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a pipeline like this

```
pipeline {
agent any
options {parallelsAlwaysFailFast()}
stages {
    stage('Non-Parallel Stage') {
        steps {
            echo 'This stage will be executed first.'
        }
    }
    stage('Parallel Stage') {
        parallel {
            stage('Branch A') {
                agent {
                    label "trfw"
                }
                steps {
                    sh 'exit -1'  // fails here
                    echo "On Branch A"
                }
            }
            stage('Branch B') {
                agent {
                    label "trfw"
                }
                steps {
                    echo "On Branch B"
                }
            }
            stage('Branch C') {
                agent {
                    label "trfw"
                }
                stages {
                    stage('Nested 1') {
                        steps {
                            echo "In stage Nested 1 within Branch C"
                        }
                    }
                    stage('Nested 2') {
                        steps {
                            echo "In stage Nested 2 within Branch C"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    stage('validator Stage') {
        steps {
            echo 'This validator stage should run even after falure of other stages.'
        }
    }
  }
}
```

In the above pipeline, when a parallel stage fails all other stages fail (parallel as well sequential) as I am using "parallelsAlwaysFailFast()" in options. I want to fail only parallel stages in case of failure but not the sequential (validator) one. Is there any way I can achieve this?

[image: Result]

Comment: You can check my answer and user as per you requirement : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67798958/how-to-execute-next-stage-in-sequential-stages-inspite-of-previous-stage-failure/67799359#67799359

Comment: @alpha89 I want to fail all parallel stages if the parallel stage fails but in case of catcherror parallel stages will keep on executing.

Comment: You can use POST build action for same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve is using post build action.

```
pipeline {
agent any
options {parallelsAlwaysFailFast()}
stages {
    stage('Non-Parallel Stage') {
        steps {
            echo 'This stage will be executed first.'
        }
    }
    stage('Parallel Stage') {
        parallel {
            stage('Branch A') {
                agent {
                    label "trfw"
                }
                steps {
                    sh 'exit -1'  // fails here
                    echo "On Branch A"
                }
            }
            stage('Branch B') {
                agent {
                    label "trfw"
                }
                steps {
                    echo "On Branch B"
                }
            }
            stage('Branch C') {
                agent {
                    label "trfw"
                }
                stages {
                    stage('Nested 1') {
                        steps {
                            echo "In stage Nested 1 within Branch C"
                        }
                    }
                    stage('Nested 2') {
                        steps {
                            echo "In stage Nested 2 within Branch C"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
  post {
            always{
                    echo 'This should run even after failure of other stages.'
                }
        }

}
```

**Jenkins Output**
[image: Jenkins Output]